# Get the selected item of a dropdown in a custom menu (and run a macro accordingly)

Tags: excel, vba, drop-down-menu

I am trying to run a macro based on user selection of the label item from a dropdown list.

The OnAction only works on the entire dropdown object and not executing macros per dropdown-list-item selection:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim oMenu As CommandBar
Set oMenu = CommandBars.Add("", msoBarPopup, , True)

Dim cbcm1 As CommandBarButton
Set cbcm1 = oMenu.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, Temporary:=True)
cbcm1.Caption = "Add new label"
cbcm1.OnAction = "AddNewLabel"

Dim cbcm2 As CommandBarComboBox
Set cbcm2 = oMenu.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlDropdown, Temporary:=True)
cbcm2.Caption = "Select label:"
cbcm2.AddItem "NVPE"   ' << this should run a macro that adds a 'NVPE' in some other range..
cbcm2.AddItem "COMP"   ' << this should run a macro that adds a 'COMP' in some other range.. and so on.
cbcm2.AddItem "HOLD"
cbcm2.AddItem "INPROG"
cbcm2.AddItem "CANC"
cbcm2.Width = 150
cbcm2.ListIndex = 1 'default
cbcm2.OnAction = "NewCommand_OnAction"
cbcm2.Style = msoComboLabel

oMenu.ShowPopup  'display the menu
Cancel = True

End Sub
```

How do I get the selected index or value (caption) of the selected item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you are missing is a `Select Case` in your event handler. Using your existing code, simply add the string `cbcm2Text` and set it to equal `cbcm2.Text`. Then, add the necessary `Select Case` prior to your `Cancel = True` statement to call your macros.
**Example:**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim oMenu As CommandBar
    Dim cbcm2Text As String
    Dim cbcm1 As CommandBarButton
    Dim cbcm2 As CommandBarComboBox
    Set oMenu = CommandBars.Add("", msoBarPopup, , True)
    Set cbcm1 = oMenu.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, Temporary:=True)
    Set cbcm2 = oMenu.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlDropdown, Temporary:=True)
    cbcm1.Caption = "Add new label"
    cbcm1.OnAction = "AddNewLabel"
    cbcm2.Caption = "Select label:"
    cbcm2.AddItem "NVPE"
    cbcm2.AddItem "COMP"
    cbcm2.AddItem "HOLD"
    cbcm2.AddItem "INPROG"
    cbcm2.AddItem "CANC"
    cbcm2.Width = 150
    cbcm2.ListIndex = 1
    cbcm2.OnAction = "NewCommand_OnAction"
    cbcm2.Style = msoComboLabel
    oMenu.ShowPopup
    cbcm2Text = cbcm2.Text
    Select Case cbcm2Text
        Case "NVPE"
            Call NVPE
        Case "COMP"
            Call COMP
        Case "HOLD"
            Call HOLD
        Case "INPROG"
            Call INPROG
        Case "CANC"
            Call CANC
    End Select
    Cancel = True
End Sub
Sub NVPE()
    MsgBox "You selected NVPE"
End Sub
Sub COMP()
    MsgBox "You selected COMP"
End Sub
Sub HOLD()
    MsgBox "You selected HOLD"
End Sub
Sub INPROG()
    MsgBox "You selected INPROG"
End Sub
Sub CANC()
    MsgBox "You selected CANC"
End Sub
```

**The preceding code produces the following result:**
[image]
[image]

Here is the relevant [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.commandbarcombobox.change) if you would like to see more examples of how to utilize combobox change events.